# Removing default serial port from vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I am using vagrant with `machine.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"`. No additional configuration.

My VM starts with open serial port `COM1` with hardcoded path pointing to `<HOMEFOLDER>/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-cloudimg-console.log`. If I understand correctly it is used by vagrant for logs.

After some research, I found that it is not Vagrant, but ubuntu official images create this Serial port for logging.

Is there a way to disable this port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [VBoxManage Customizations](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/configuration.html#vboxmanage-customizations)  that relies in the [modify](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvm) command:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uart1", "off" ]
  vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uart2", "off" ]
  vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uart3", "off" ]
  vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uart4", "off" ]
end
```

Comment: Another possible solution is: ```config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", "disconnected"]
   end ```